# difference between $.getJSON and $.get

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Is there really a difference in these two calls? If you use getJSON, you still have to declare `format=json` in the url...

And you can do the same in `$.get()`, and iterate through the JSON-object.

Or am I way off here?

Comment: What you have to declare in the URL has nothing to do with jQuery. Nor would that be the case for all sites - certainly not for one of mine ;-)

Comment: I was just saying that you have to declare in the url that you're looking for a JSON result, even if you're using getJSON. And you would declare it in the url for $.get() too. Just wondering what one does, that the other doesn't...

Comment: You actually **are** out of track here . while using **getJSON()** method you **DON'T** have to explicitly pass the datatype but in **get()** Method you will explixitly **HAVE TO** . See the comment above by yehuda. It tells the whole story or else visit [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: I did saw that you accepted the answer.  But frankly speaking nobody pointed the fact that i mentioned as straightforwardly as i did . Maybe you are clear now about it . So good for you !

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The following two snippets are equivalent:

```
$.get("/some/url", {data: "value"}, function(json) { 
  // use json here
}, "json")

$.getJSON("/some/url", {data: "value"}, function(json) {
  // use json here
});
```

Saying that a request is for `JSON` means two things:

- jQuery sends an `Accept: application/json` header
- jQuery interprets the inbound response, converts it into a JavaScript Object, and passes it into the callback (so you don't have to mess with eval or other conversion mechanism).

A number of server-side frameworks (such as Rails) automatically detect the `Accept` header and handle the request appropriately. If you are using a different framework or rolling your own, you can inspect the `Accept` header to detect the format (instead of inspecting the parameters).

Comment: I should also point out that the reason the Accept header solution was added was to cater to frameworks that handle it gracefully, making the communication between jQuery and such frameworks (e.g. Rails) seamless.

Answer (score 7):

I think the documentation explains it quite clearly!

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype

Load a remote **page** using an HTTP GET request.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON#urldatacallback

Load JSON **data** using an HTTP GET request.

Remember, these are just abstractions of the .ajax method

Comment: But one can still use $.get to recieve JSON data, right? If the page you're calling returns a JSON-object?

Comment: Sure, I suppose, as long as you specify the 'data' argument as json. If the page is going to return json, why not just use the getJSON method? Again, these are just abstractions to simplify ajax calls, from the base .ajax method. They are there to make things easier for you, not to complicate!

Comment: I've used $.get with no data argument and it works just fine. The API doc says the default for the data argument is an "intelligent guess", and so apparently jQuery is guessing correctly in my use cases ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The differences between $.getJSOn and $.get are in parameters:

1. $.getJSON accepts plain objects as data while $.get accepts plain objects or string.
2. $.get has dataType  parameter.

So, using $.get with dataType: JSON would work exactly the same as $.getJSON.