# Rails 4 controller not returning well formed JSON

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, coffeescript

I am building a web application using Rails 4 and I stumbled upon some weird behavior between Rails controllers and JQuery, I am not sure if it is because I am doing something wrong or if there's really a misinterpretation of Rails returned JSON by JQuery. See the following coffee script:

**Coffee script:**

```
$.get('/get_experiment', (data) -> 
  console.log 'Success:'
  console.log JSON.parse data
).error (data) ->
  console.log 'Failure:'
  console.log JSON.parse data.responseText
```

We just call a controller's method via GET, handle both success and failure and display the data returned.

**Controller:**

```
def get_experiment
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render json: {} }
  end
end
```

This controller simply replies with an empty Hash.

---

When running this example, the console displays the empty JSON with the 'Failure' text, which apparently indicates that it considers the JSON to be malformed.

I do not understand why an empty hash is considered malformed JSON. If you replace that with `render json: {foo: 'bar'}`, it will still call the error method.

Comment: I tried this and it worked fine (showed success text with parsed JSON hash). Is it possible that some other code is messing with your response? Maybe a before_filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

1. In your CoffeeScript file use `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.get()`
2. Also change the path from `/get_experiment` to `/get_experiment.json`
3. In your controller use `format.json { ... }` instead of `format.js`

### Explanation

1. This step is not necessary. But if you use `$.getJSON`:

   - jQuery sends an `Accept: application/json` header
   - jQuery interprets the inbound response, converts it into a JavaScript Object, and passes it into the callback (so you don't have to mess with eval or other conversion mechanism).
     (*From [difference between $.getJSON and $.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079205/difference-between-getjson-and-get)*)
2. If there is no extension (like .js, .xml, .json) in requested document, Rails assumes that client requests for a HTML page. But, since you didn't specify `format.html` in controller action, this will lead to error.
3. Since now you're requesting for a JSON document, you need to specify the proper handler in controller action.

Comment: The direct answer to my problem is your third point. the `format.js` was causing the bug. I could not find any documentation on it and I just stumbled upon this http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/08/embracing-rest-with-mind-body-and-soul/ if anyone gets curious. Thank you Andrei!

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap your JSON in an array like this: `render json: [{}]`, it then executes the success method rather than the error method.

So in definitive I have found a workaround to my problem, but I am puzzled as to why I cant simply do things like:  `render json: @user.to_json`

Instead I have to do:  `render json: [@user.to_json]`

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

> When running this example, the console displays the empty JSON with the 'Failure' text, which apparently indicates that it considers the JSON to be malformed.

In my understanding, this is not what's happening: **The `error` callback is called because the request failed** (returned a non-200 status) and has nothing to do with the json being invalid (which it isn't).

To debug your problem further I suggest the following:

- Inspect the http request in your browser and check whether it is actually succeeding (status 200)
- Inspect your rails log and check that the request is actually succeeding (you should see something like "Completed 200 OK")
- Do a `console.log(data)` in both your success and error handler and check what `data` actually is. At the moment you try to `JSON.parse` once `data` and once `data.responseText`...
- Read through the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/, especially the sections about `dataType`: if the server returns a proper json response (with correct content type) or if you explicitly set `dataType` to `'json'` in the request, then jQuery should parse the response automatically for you and the `data` object in the callback should already be the parsed response content...

Answer (score 0):

Are you properly using strong parameters?  I've had this issue in the past because I didn't allow those params to pass through.

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/