# Serve either JSON or HTML based on what was requested?

Tags: json, node.js, httprequest

I'm using nodejs and I want to make a unified handler to serve either JSON or HTML based on which one was requested from the client.

So far I though of simply passing a variable in the request body that I can check before serving

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
    if (req.body.requested=='JSON')
        res.json(...
    else
        res.render(...
```

But instead of passing the variable in request body, is there something in the headers or something intrinsically different between `jQuery.getJSON()` and `jQuery.get()` that I use to make the differentiation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a better way is to simply check the `Accept` header of the request. For example, if the header says:

```
Accept: application/json
```

then it is appropriate to send JSON back. Or for example,

```
Accept: text/html
```

then you send back html.

Comment: ...and according http://stackoverflow.com/a/1080985/4323 this header is automatically sent by `getJSON()`.